# not able to out put content to a text file with line breaks

Tags: powershell

I am using `out-file` to send content to a text file, even though it usually takes care of putting line breaks in between one line after another, it is not happening in this case.

Output is something like below:

```
appleballcountry
```

I was expecting it to be as below

```
apple
ball 
country
```

Below is the code snippet that I am using, please ignore the variables (as this is just a work in progress).

```
foreach ($li in $bin) {
    $list2 = $list1 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li}
    #$list2 #| out-file info2.txt
    foreach ($li2 in $list2) {
        $li3 += $li2 | where-object {$_ -like $li -and $_ -like "*Error*"} 
        $li3 | out-file info2.txt # it's this part that I am not able to get to 
        #the text file with line breaks
        break
    }        
}
```

I am just beginning out with powershell and stack overflow in general and am aware that I might not be giving entire information here.

Also, I am unable to give powershell version as of now as I am not sure how to.

Comment: You should better explain what you are after (and what $bin/$list1 contain). 1st the code is redundant, $li2 only contains items like $li - so the second where can be `where-object {$_ -like "*Error*"`. 2nd the `out-file info2.txt` will overwrite on every iteration. 3rd read [Get-Help about_break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Just run `$PSVersionTable` to get your PS Version :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with `out-file` but your `$li3 string`.

When you do the `+=` PowerShell will just mush the words together, and not regard them as seperate objects.

What you could do is add the `where-object` to your `foreach` statement, and manually assign a new line.

```
foreach ($li in $bin)
{
$list2 = $list1 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li}
foreach ($li2 in $list2 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li -and $_ -notlike "Error"})
{
$li3 += $li2 + "`r`n"
$li3 | out-file info2.txt
break
}
}
```

Might also be a good idea to move the `out-file` outside of the loop.

Comment: That worked !!
thanks for pointing it out, seems natural now that you have pointed it out. I just put the appending to out-file part inside the loop out of habit..

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When working with the `+=` operator you are concatenating both strings `$li3` and `$li2`.

```
PS C:\temp> $string1 = "new"
PS C:\temp> $string2 = "year"
PS C:\temp> $string1 += $string2
PS C:\temp> $string1
newyear
```

I see two alternatives for your foreach loop here:

Option1 you simply append to your text file:

```
foreach ($li2 in $list2 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li -and $_ -notlike "Error"})
{
  $li2 | Out-File -Append info2.txt
}
```

Option2 if you need an object:

```
$li3 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
foreach ($li2 in $list2 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li -and $_ -notlike "Error"})
{
  $li3.Add($li2)
}
$li3 | Out-File info2.txt
```

Your code logic can probably be improved, you're filtering two times on `$li`:

```
$list2 = $list1 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li}
foreach ($li2 in $list2 | Where-Object {$_ -like $li -and $_ -notlike "Error"})
```